# R - Converting table to a list for export to an csv line by line for each cell

Tags: r

I am working a solution of exporting a table in R as tab stopped csv-file, where each cell in the table is defined by a row in the export file. I did search for any similar problems already, but only found solutions to read in data into a table, but not export it with the necessary kind of structure.

I have already the code for reading in data and generating a table where a string is seperated and a variable for each word from a string is defined.

Now I am not succeeding in writing a code which generates the desired export structure.

The desired output should look like this for the example below:

- ID0001   Butter
- ID0001   Jelly
- ID0001   Peanut
- ID0002   Peanut
- ID0003   Butter
- ID0004   Storm
- ID0005   Butter
- ID0005   Storm
- ID0005   Wind

I need exact that structure as shown above as further processing in another application is necessary.

Hope someone could help me with the code. I am thankful for any advice (sample code, packages, etc.)

```
#Generate Test data
df_TEST <- structure(list(ID = c("ID0001", "ID0002", "ID0003", "ID0004", 
                            "ID0005"), strings = c("Peanut Butter Jelly", "Peanut", "Butter", 
                                                   "Storm", "Storm Wind Butter")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

#Get all unique words
all_words <- sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(df_TEST$strings, "\\W"))))

#Generate table
df_Result<-cbind(df_TEST, sapply(all_words, function(x) 1 * grepl(x, df_TEST$strings)))

#MISSING: Generate structure for output

#Code for csv-Export with tabstopp (done)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try the base R code below

```
word_list <- Map(unique,strsplit(df_TEST$strings,"\\W"))

dfout <- data.frame(ID = rep(df_TEST$ID,lengths(word_list)),
                    Word = unlist(word_list))
```

such that

```
> dfout
      ID   Word
1 ID0001 Peanut
2 ID0001 Butter
3 ID0001  Jelly
4 ID0002 Peanut
5 ID0003 Butter
6 ID0004  Storm
7 ID0005  Storm
8 ID0005   Wind
9 ID0005 Butter
```

Comment: Great! This simple code improves even my former version.